# How can I create a permanent/persistent PPTP VPN from a Windows Server 2008 (R2) machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, site-to-site-vpn

A while ago I managed to create a permanent (or persistent) VPN to a remote server from my Windows 2008 server. However I can't remember how I did this and I can't find any articles explaining how you do it. I do not want to have to manually dial the connection after restarting the server - it needs to be there all the time. I remember that Windows Server 2008 has an option for this, but I can't find it within the network settings.

Comment: I wish people would actually state why they're downvoting my question (or the answers).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

RRAS, create VPN, set persistent flag in properties. Simple like that.